# Swift iOS - Resize collectionLayout on a screen rotation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, collectionview

I have a collection view (basically UICollectionView) and collection layout (UICollectionViewFlowLayout). I am trying to find a way to resize ItemSize based on a device orientation. However I cannot find a way. The class inherits only from UIView.

```
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    //collectionLayout.invalidateLayout()

    if UIScreen.main.bounds.width < UIScreen.main.bounds.height { //portrait
        collectionLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    } else {
        collectionLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    collectionLayout.collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()

    if collectionView != nil {
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

I also tried to use the invalidateLayout() on collectionLayout but also no change. Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be using constraints for this to work. More over, you need to be using SIZE CLASSES.

Here is a tutorial, it is in swift 4 but the principles are the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLh0RIQmCr4

Here is another link to more tutorial for what you need

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/what-are-size-classes